# Unable to bind datetime value with datetime control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application. My model has a DateTime field i.e.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:h:mm tt}")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }
```

I have to show this in a DateTime control on front end (cshtml). My code for this in cshtml is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.model.CompletedDate, new { type = "datetime-local" })
```

Value of **model.CompletedDate** is **2020-06-15 11:00:00.000** but i don't get this value binded with my control. I get this:

[image]

I have to use DateTime control and can not use simple textbox. Can anyone help me. I am stuck here and didn't find anything on the google yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string needs to be `"{0:s}"`, i tried this and it's work fine for me :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.model.CompletedDate,"{0:s}", new { type = "datetime-local" })
```

I hope you find this helpful.